# iOS Define SEL from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

I'm trying to have another object call a selector. I'm attempting to define this selector from another class by defining the selector property. It doesn't seem to be working like I expect.

ComboBox.h

```
@property (nonatomic) SEL onComboSelect;
```

ComboBox.m

```
-(void)doneClicked:(id) sender
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; //hides the pickerView
    NSLog(@"DONE CLICKED CALLED");
    [self performSelector:@selector(onComboSelect)];
}
```

OtherClass.h

```
@interface OtherClass : BaseViewController
{
    ComboBox *combo;
}

-(void)comboSelector;
```

OtherClass.m

```
// in viewDidLoad
combo = [[ComboBox alloc] init];
combo.onComboSelect = @selector(comboSelector);

-(void)comboSelector
{
    NSLog(@"COMBO SELECTOR");
}
```

I see "DONE CLICK CALLED" in the logs, but not "COMBO SELECTOR". So I know doneClicked is being called, but the selector doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are calling `performSelector:` on `self`. You need to call it on an instance of `OtherClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `@selector` is just a method name - it does not include any context about the class on which it is defined.  So this `[self performSelector:@selector(onComboSelect)]` is just invoking the method on `self`.  In addition to the selector, you also need a reference to the object on which you want to call it.

Notice how some built-in classes (like `UIControl`) take both a `target` object and `action` selector.

Answer (score 1):

There are a 2 major issues in your code.

**1.**

`onComboSelect` is a `SEL` so no need to use the `@selector` again.

Instead of:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(onComboSelect)];
```

Use :

```
[self performSelector:onComboSelect];
```

**2.**

You are calling the selector on `self` from ComboBox class, so it'll call the selector on ComboBox object (if defined) not on OtherClass object

Comment: Ok, when I change [self performSelector:@selector(onComboSelect)]; to [self performSelector:onComboSelect]; I get a warning that says "PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown". Then when I run my app and try the button that calls doneClicked, I get an exception. It says -[ComboBox comboSelector]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15527420.

Comment: @JaredPrice: the exception is due to the second point I mentioned in my answer

Comment: I figured it out now. I posted my solution as an answer. I appreciate the help.

Comment: SEL is a point of object_seletor,and in object_seletor runtime can find the object_methodstruct objc_method {
    SEL method_name                                          OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    char *method_types                                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    IMP method_imp                                           OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
}

Answer (score 0):

Your answers were helpful. Here is what I did:

added to ComboBox.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *parentViewController;
```

added to ComboBox.m

```
-(void)doneClicked:(id) sender
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; //hides the pickerView

    if ([parentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(comboSelector)])
        [parentViewController performSelector:@selector(comboSelector)];
}
```

added to OtherClass.m

```
combo.parentViewController = self;
```

@property (nonatomic) SEL onComboSelect <-- This property is not needed in ComboBox.h.

Comment: While this works, there are a few things to watch out for: 1. Object properties should always be designated `strong` or `weak`.  Properties are `assign` by default, which is similar to `weak`, except that `weak` properties are automatically zeroed when the referenced object is freed.  2. Instead of catching all exceptions and assuming the cause was an undefined selector, you can use `respondsToSelector:` beforehand

Answer (score 0):

SEL is a point of objc_seletor,and in object_seletor runtime can find the 
objc_method ,that define

```
objc_method {
    SEL method_name                                          OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    char *method_types                                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    IMP method_imp                                           OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
}
```

and IMP is the point of method,and you can find this in "runtime.h" file.
Any noe kow how to find objc_method by object_seletor ? and  I cannot find the define of objc_seletor struct.